# call methods inside controller from a different class javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have a guicontroller class which shows a black circle. And I've made this method inside that guicontroller class to change the color of the circle.
Object *light* is a Circle.

```
public void getLight(){
    light.setFill(Color.RED);
}
```

When I call this function from a different class with the use of:

```
guicontroller ctrl = new guicontroller();

ctrl.getLight();
```

nothing happens in my gui, it calls the getLight() method but does not fill the circle.

Comment: what kind of an object is light?

Comment: where's your Graphics object? you need to to do g.fill(light) at some point to have it show up.

Comment: I've used an fxml file and filled it there.

Comment: You're creating a new controller instance and calling the method on that. The `light` field in that instance is not part of your scene graph. You need to get the controller instance from the `FXMLLoader` when you load and display the fxml, and call the method on that instance.